# Keyboard shortcut to select the full directory path of the active window

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, file-management, active-directory

Need to select (then copy) the **full directory path of the active window** by keyboard shortcut. Is it possible?

For example, I need to put into the clipboard (so I can insert into command prompt, anaconda, etc.):

```
M:\shopping\garden\fertilizer\banana\
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using File Explorer (Windows Explorer), you need to combine different keys. Press <kbd>F4</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Or

As mentioned by @hextech on the comments, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Comment: note: it's also possible to access the explorer link by pressing CTRL+L. F4 is faster, but CTRL+L works in browsers as well.

Comment: @hextech Noted. I will add it to the answer.

Comment: Ctrl + L works perfectly and selects the current path

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Explorer and most web browsers, hit `Alt-D` to select the path in the address bar then `Ctrl-C` to copy.

This `Alt-D` keyboard accelerator recalls the URL bar in Internet Explorer 6 and earlier, which was preceded by the word "Address" with an underlined "d":

[image: Screenshot of Internet Explorer 6]

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Context Menu</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd> (note that this may differ if you have non-standard shell context menu entries with overlapping mnemonic/access keys).  This may produce more keystrokes on it's own, but you can circumvent that with an .ahk script to achieve a single-input solution.  You can technically bind *any* of the mentioned methods through AHK actually, but it can be a bit of a learning curve for those not aquainted with the scripting nuances, particularly when multiple modifier keys are involved.